# the total differential equation $(y^2z - y^3 +x^2y)dx - (x^2z +x^3 -xy^2)dy +(x^2y - xy^2)dz=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In solving the total differential equation $$(y^2z - y^3 +x^2y)dx - (x^2z +x^3 -xy^2)dy +(x^2y - xy^2)dz=0$$
Substituting $x =uz$ and $y=vz$ and reached at a position where, i face the following
$$(v^2 - v^3 +u^2v)du - (u^2+u^3-uv^2)dv=0$$

I am stuck here please help!!

Comment: Take one variable as constant...say, z=constant..Then , $dz=0$. Then proceed ...

Comment: Are you sure of your last equation. I think it should be $(v^2 - v^3 +u^2v)dv - (u^2+u^3-uv^2)du=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $(v^2 - v^3 +u^2v)du - (u^2+u^3-uv^2)dv=0$ is OK. To continue, see below :

[image]

Instead of such a complicated calculus, a little bit of observation would have given the integrating factor $\frac{1}{u^2v^2}$ for $(v^2 - v^3 +u^2v)du - (u^2+u^3-uv^2)dv=0$
$$\left(\frac{1}{u^2}-\frac{v}{u^2}+\frac{1}{v}\right)du+\left(-\frac{1}{v^2}-\frac{u}{v^2}+\frac{1}{u}\right)dv=0$$
$$d\left(-\frac{1}{u}+\frac{v}{u}+\frac{u}{v}+\frac{1}{v}\right)=0$$
$$-\frac{1}{u}+\frac{v}{u}+\frac{u}{v}+\frac{1}{v}=constant$$
$$-\frac{z}{x}+\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{z}{y}=constant$$

Answer (score 0):

It's all equation devided by x^2 y^2.
Now we  get

(z-y/x^2 +1/y)dx-(z+x/y^2 - 1/x)dy+(1/y-1/x)dz

d(x/y) +d(y/x) +z(dx-dy) +(1/y-1/x)dz

d(x/y) +d(y/x) +d(z/y) - d(z/x) = 0

x+y + log y - log x = c

x+y+ log  y/ x = c

x + y + log y / x = c.

Is a required solution.